# Summing the number of matched LIKE statments in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a MySQL query in the following format:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `val1` IN (x,y,z)
AND (
  `val2` LIKE '%a%' OR
  `val2` LIKE '%b%' OR
  `val2` LIKE '%c%' OR
  ...
  `val2` LIKE '%x%'
)
```

and what I want to do is add up the number of times those LIKE statements make a match. For example if it finds a match for say a,e and y the total for that would be 3 which I can then use an ORDER BY to search by the rows with most "hits".

Edit: I miss used % as & in my query as a wildcard.

Comment: Why all those likes? Are you attempting to use `&` as a literal item because the only two wildcards `LIKE` accepts are `%` and `_`?  Seems like you could just as easily write `val2 IN ('&a&', '&b&' ...)` or do regex match like `val2 REGEXP '&.&'`

Comment: In my haste to write the question I miss used % with &. I am using % and not & as a wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add them together in MySQL:

```
SELECT *,
       ((`val2` LIKE '&a&') +
        (`val2` LIKE '&b&') +
        (`val2` LIKE '&c&') +
        ...
       ) as nummatches
FROM `table` 
WHERE `val1` IN (x,y,z)
AND (
  `val2` LIKE '&a&' OR
  `val2` LIKE '&b&' OR
  `val2` LIKE '&c&' OR
  ...
  `val2` LIKE '&x&'
)
```

In fact, you can simplify the query to:

```
SELECT *,
       ((`val2` LIKE '&a&') +
        ( `val2` LIKE '&b&') +
        (`val2` LIKE '&c&') +
        ...
       ) as nummatches
FROM `table` 
WHERE `val1` IN (x,y,z)
having nummatches > 0;
```